# What Are the Minimum KML File Requirement to Draw Multiple Polygons?

Tags: kml

My application is trying to export a KML file. The file should contain a series of polygons that represent sales territories. The territories cover the whole of the US.

I've followed the instruction for creating polygons on the [KML tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut). The file output from my application can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/leac4eb4yeu8n27/Test.kml?dl=0). I've tried to import this into QGIS and MyMaps. Both application parse the file but only show some of the territories.

My question is what am I missing? What are the minimum fields required to show multiple shapes with multiple polygons (and holes).

Comment: The documentation contains valid samples. If you are having difficulty with a specific small file, post it in a code block here.

Comment: Have you tried to validate the KML output against the KML schema?  When I try in my parser I get lots of errors like: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":outerBoundaryIs}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":innerBoundaryIs, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":PolygonSimpleExtensionGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":PolygonObjectExtensionGroup}' is expected.`

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your `test.kml` file is that it contains multiple `<outerBoundaryIs>` elements per `<Polygon>`.

If you look at the XSD schema for KML (that is the definition of what's allowed/required in a KML file) you can see that only one such element is allowed per Polygon element:

```
<element name="Polygon" type="kml:PolygonType" substitutionGroup="kml:AbstractGeometryGroup"/>
<complexType name="PolygonType" final="#all">
<complexContent>
  <extension base="kml:AbstractGeometryType">
    <sequence>
      <element ref="kml:extrude" minOccurs="0"/>
      <element ref="kml:tessellate" minOccurs="0"/>
      <element ref="kml:altitudeModeGroup" minOccurs="0"/>
      <element ref="kml:outerBoundaryIs" minOccurs="0"/>
      <element ref="kml:innerBoundaryIs" minOccurs="0"
        maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <element ref="kml:PolygonSimpleExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0"
        maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <element ref="kml:PolygonObjectExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0"
        maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
  </extension>
</complexContent>
```

I'm not an KML expert, but looking at the reference/schema, I think you probably need to use `<MultiGeometry>` and not `<Polygon>` to enclose all your `<LinearRing><coordinates>...` sections per Placemark, so you would have something like:

```
   <Placemark>
        <name>305</name>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates> -65.525367,18.356347,10 ...</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates> -65.281155,18.141504,10 ...</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates> -67.835002,18.114775,...</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates> -65.227244,18.318174,10 ...
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates> -66.513506,17.902906,10 -66.509611,17.898928,10
                    -66.529663,17.883756,10 -66.526144,17.893284,10 -66.513506,17.902906,10
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates> -67.477922,18.390544,10 ...</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It's not complicated but it's also not well documented:

Simple Polygon has this structure:

```
<Polygon>
  <outerBoundary>
    <LinearRing>
      <coordinates>
        ...
      </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundary>
</Polygon>
```

A polygon with a hole has this format (there can be multiple innerBoundaries):

```
<Polygon>
  <outerBoundary>
    <LinearRing>
      <coordinates>
        ...
      </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundary>
  <innerBoundary>
    <LinearRing>
      <coordinates>
        ...
      </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </innerBoundary>
</Polygon>
```

And a multi-part shapes has this format:

```
<MultiGeometry>
  <Polygon> 
    ...
  </Polygon>
  <Polygon> 
    ...
  </Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```